# Apache POI and Excel VBA performance comparison

Tags: apache, excel, vba, apache-poi

in term of performance speed comparsion and without consider the development time

is that Excel VBA always faster than Apache POI when perform same task?

e.g. - fill background color/font formatting 
     - convert csv into excel file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I hear people smarter than me say all the time: *it depends*. You will have to go through some testing yourself to see what gives you the best performance for the tasks you want to accomplish.

If I would have to guess than I'd go for VBA. Chances are you'll be able to do much more than is available in POI too. The choice in the end will also be influenced by experience and architecture and ...